# How to download my site deployed with AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The site runs on sqlite, and I want to backup my database.

Where is the physical location of my site? Is it possible to download the whole code base of my site? I searched the associated S3 bucket, and I can only find the source bundle used to upload the site and that's not what I want.

Comment: Beanstalk servers are designed to be ephemeral- state such as a database should be stored elsewhere. You may be able to ssh to the machine to access it.

Comment: but the thing is that sqlite is serverless, and is deployed with everything else of the site at the same place.. i don't wanna change the database to like MySQL.. so there is no way i can do that with EB right?

Comment: so if i change the way i deploy the site, is it possible to do what i wanted?